# Second derivative must attain $\frac{f''(c)}{2} = \frac{f(x)}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

$f$ is differentiable twice in $R$, $f(0)=0, f'(0)=0$.

Show that for any $x > 0$, $c$ exists, $0 < c < x$ such that $\frac{f''(c)}{2} = \frac{f(x)}{x^2}$.

I tried using Mean Value Theorem to express some points on the first/second derivative, but I just can't get that expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: For a fixed $x$, set $g(t) = f(t) - t^2 f(x) / x^2$ for $t \in (0,x)$.  Then showing that such a $c$ exists is equivalent to showing that there exists a $c$ so that $g''(c) = 0$.  What data do we have about $g$ at $0$ and at $x$?

Answer (score 1):

If f is twice differentiable we have by Taylor's theorem
$$
f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac{f''(c)}{2}x^2
$$
for some $c\in (0,x)$ (this is the remainder term). Since $f(0)=f'(0)=0$, this is 
$$
f(x)=\frac{f''(c)}{2}x^2
$$

Comment: Wouldnt that be $f^{''}(0)$ in the first equation?

Comment: no, that term is the remainder term

Comment: So arnt you expanding $f(x)$ about $x = 0$?

Comment: @sbp I am indeed

Comment: So if that's the case then the second derivative shouldn't be at $x = 0$?

Comment: No. Look up the remainder term in the expansion